# Highlight selected hybrid text in C# webBrowser control

Tags: c#, html, .net, webbrowser-control, highlighting

As [this suggestion](http://www.codewrecks.com/blog/index.php/2009/02/13/highlight-words-in-webbrowser-control/) I'm using the following code to highlight selected text in webBrowser:

```
using mshtml;

    if (webBrowser1.Document != null)
    {
        IHTMLDocument2 document = webBrowser1.Document.DomDocument as IHTMLDocument2;
        if (document != null)
        {
            IHTMLSelectionObject currentSelection = document.selection;
            IHTMLTxtRange range = currentSelection.createRange() as IHTMLTxtRange;
            if (range != null)
            {
                string oldText = range.text.Replace("\n", "</br>");
                string newHtmlText = "<span style='background-color: rgb(255, 255, 0);'>" +oldText + "</span>";                        
                range.pasteHTML(newHtmlText);                        
            }
        }
    }
```

When a normal text is selected every thing is OK. But as you can see in this image when some hybrid text is selected, it will damage the document.

[image]

Sometimes may the selected text contains tables and other formatted texts. How can I highlight any part of document without changing the format?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've found the answer.

The `mshtml` has full options to manage the text. [Here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms536419%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) is the syntax of execCommand to do any changes to the document.

In this way you do not need to parse the html yourself or khnow about html elements.

```
using mshtml;

if (webBrowser1.Document != null)
{
    IHTMLDocument2 document = webBrowser1.Document.DomDocument as IHTMLDocument2;
    if (document != null)
    {
        IHTMLSelectionObject currentSelection = document.selection;
        IHTMLTxtRange range = currentSelection.createRange() as IHTMLTxtRange;
        if (range != null)
        {
            range.execCommand("BackColor", false, "FFFF00");                      
        }
    }
}
```